# Save heap data in a mapped file without copying?

Tags: c, linux, multiprocessing

I am working on a program which should share data among multiple processes. I use mmap() to map shared data. But the problem is that the pointer returned by mmap() is not very "flexible" (compared with pointer return by malloc()). The buffer (shared data) needs to be resized dynamically. So now what I did is still manipulating the shared data in heap (malloc, realloc..) and then copy it to a buffer which is returned by mmap(). Other processes need load the shared data from mmap() buffer to heap.

This brings some performance penality. I am wondering if there exist a way to assign data in heap to a mmaped file directly without copying?

Comment: Does the region need to grow while the other processes are viewing it?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It only need to be dynamic in the writing process. Once the writing process finishes writing, this region can be immutable.

Comment: Then just stuff the data into the `mmap`ed area, and be done. In any case, unless you have *irrefutable measurements* that tell you this data copying is a serious bottleneck in your program, just don't worry. Your time is precious, computers are cheap. Also remember that [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Answer (score 0):

Use `mremap` to grow mmap'd regions.

```
// first grow the underlying file, then:
char *newp = mremap(p, oldsize, newsize, MREMAP_MAYMOVE);
if (newp == MAP_FAILED) {
    // handle error, probably munmap(p)
}
p = newp;
```

`MREMAP_MAYMOVE` tells `mremap` that it may change the virtual address of the mapping. That does not mean it has to copy any data around, just that it changes pages' mappings in the virtual address space.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [application checkpointing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing), notably you might want to use [BLCR](http://crd.lbl.gov/groups-depts/ftg/projects/current-projects/BLCR/) library.

BTW, you don't need to `malloc` then `mmap`. You could directly use `mmap`.